# Updating the ListViewItem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I can't find a proper answer on how to update the `ListView` after I inserted another item.
When I add `ListView1.Clear()` and `DatabaseSelect()` in `Button1` there was nothing to view.

How do I refresh my `ListView` everytime I insert new items?

Here is the code of filling the ListView:

```
Function DatabaseSelect()
    Try

        myDA.SelectCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
        myDA.SelectCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM FullName")
        myDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        myDA.Fill(myDS)

        For Each myDR As DataRow In myDS.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim myListview As New ListViewItem()
            myListview.SubItems.Add(myDR(0))
            myListview.SubItems.Add(myDR(1))
            myListview.SubItems.Add(myDR(2))
            myListview.SubItems.Add(myDR(3))
            ListView1.Items.Add(myListview)
        Next
        conn.Open()
        myDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

Here is the code of inserting item to ListView:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
        myDA.InsertCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
        myDA.InsertCommand.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO FullName (FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) VALUES(@firstname,@middlename,@lastname)")
        myDA.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        myDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "FirstName").Value = TextBox1.Text
        myDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@middlename", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "MiddleName").Value = TextBox2.Text
        myDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "LastName").Value = TextBox3.Text
        conn.Open()
        myDA.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: how do you bind your ListView (xaml / code) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call Function DatabaseSelect() in Button Click Event..

Add DatabaseSelect() After conn.Close()

May be this will help you.

Comment: it wouldn't work the same problem still exist. thank you for your kindness.